# List with number input and its retrieval

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

If I created a list and designed an `EditText`(number input) for every item, how can i retrieve the input and display it on another page (either in a table or another list?) I'm new to android studio, please someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn Bundle and Intent , by using Intent you can pass data from one Activity to another Activity .

And you can add any primitive data into Bundle and then add bundle object into calling activity intent and then get Bundle from Intent in Next Activity.

Also you can add `ArrayList` into Bundle .

To use the above do this:

In 'sending' activity use:

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new Arraylist<String>();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayList("arraylist", arraylist);
```

In 'receiving' activity use:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> arraylist  = extras.getStringArrayList("arraylist");
```

Comment: Hi @Chetan Joshi, I followed a tutorial on creating a List using adapter and array... Do I design the EditText in normal ways correct? (in adapter)

Comment: `EditText` in `ListView` is not working properly. if you have input  Text Box then its ok .

Comment: You need to open a dialog to get input for particular child item in List .